# How to use Noembed for link preview in PHP

Tags: php

I found noembed as a free alternative of embed.ly
But There is no DOCS for using its service.

Can anyone help me to use NoEmbed in PHP and getting the Thumb Link back from JSON return?

(I think This can be solved using CURL, but as I don't know too much about CURL, I am looking at you, No Curl:preferred)

Comment: https://noembed.com/ shows what request you need to make, and what the data structure you will get in return will look like. What more documentation do you need?

Comment: Example of a proper request using diffrent languages

Comment: How to make HTTP requests in language X, is something you should be able to go research on your own. Don’t expect such basics to get explicitly documented everywhere HTTP is “used”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is what you are looking for.

This sample should be self-explanatory.

```php
$json = file_get_contents('http://noembed.com/embed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DbDOYN-6gdRE');
var_dump(json_decode($json)->thumbnail_url);
```